# Same Code in Multiple Classes without Inheritence

Tags: c#, inheritance, antlr4

I'm using AnTLR's plugin for C# in Visual Studio 2015. AnTLR has a class `ParserRuleContext` from which all the parser rule classes inherit. The parser rule classes themselves are declared as partial classes, like this:

```
public partial class SomeRuleContext : ParserRuleContext {
    /* stuff goes here */
}
```

The definition of `ParserRuleContext` looks like this:

```
public class ParserRuleContext : RuleContext
{
}
```

I'm implementing my own partial classes for all parser rules to do custom stuff with the parser tree. I would like to be able to add a property to the `ParserRuleContext` (and other properties/fields/methods later), but `ParserRuleContext` is not declared as `partial`. Since the rule classes all already inherit from another class, I can't make my partial implementations of them also inherit from a class. Extension methods don't get me all the functionality I want (can't add properties/fields), and Interfaces have me literally copy/pasting the exact same code into every class. As a software developer, that last part almost literally makes me nauseous.

I have considered the idea of adding a single, constant property that points at an object that contains the functionality I want, but that solution feels clunky to me and adds an extra call to any of the members of the type. So this:

```
SomeRuleContextInstance.CustomProperty = new FileInfo( "path" );
```

becomes this:

```
SomeRuleContextInstance.CommonFunctionality.CustomProperty = new FileInfo( "path" );
```

I would prefer a better solution.

Can anyone provide a way to either modify the `ParserRuleContext` base class or otherwise not have me copy/paste code everywhere? Could this be done with Reflection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an additional inheritance level between the concrete context classes and `ParserRuleContext`.

Just create a class that inherits `ParserRuleContext`:

```
public abstract class MyParserRuleContext : ParserRuleContext
{
    // Whatever you want here
}
```

And then tell your grammar to use it with the following option:

```
grammar MyGrammar;

options {
     contextSuperClass = MyParserRuleContext;
}

// ...
```

Comment: Two notes I found with this: A) I need `MyParserRuleContext` class to be in a different namespace and B) you can't run the grammar from the command line using the Java target to get a visualization of the parse tree (obv ... I haz facepalm now). The namespace issue was solved by setting `options=Namespace.Names.MoreNames.MyParserRuleContext`. Otherwise, this is perfect. Thanks! (All grammar options can be found [here](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/options.md)).